# Correct format specifier to print a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory

I with the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numOfClasses;

    do{
    printf("How many classes do you have?\t");
    scanf("%d", &numOfClasses);
    }while(numOfClasses < 1);

    int count = numOfClasses;
    char nameOfClass[30];
    int numOfGrades[30];
    printf("Which classes do you have, how many grades in each class?\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            scanf("%s %d", &nameOfClass[i], &numOfGrades[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            printf("%s : %d\n", nameOfClass[i], numOfGrades[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want this program to to ask the user to input a class and the number of grades in that class. Later I will try to input each individual grade in that class, but for now I want to solve this.

When I run this I get this error message:

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
printf("%s : %d\n", nameOfClass[i], numOfGrades[i]);
       ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `char nameOfClass[30]` should be two dimensional array as `char nameOfClass[30][30]`.
As you are reading the name of classes. So, I changed it to two dimensional array. And you are reading string array using the statement:
`scanf("%s %d", &nameOfClass[i], &numOfGrades[i]);` If you do not use two dimensional array then, your `nameOfClass` variable will point only last class name which is incorrect.

```
    int count = numOfClasses;
    char nameOfClass[30][30];
    int numOfGrades[30];
    printf("Which classes do you have, how many grades in each class?\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            scanf("%s %d", nameOfClass[i], &numOfGrades[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            printf("%s : %d\n", nameOfClass[i], numOfGrades[i]);
    }
```

Comment: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[30]’

Comment: What if `count` is greater than 30?

Comment: Should be no address-of operator on the first parameter: `scanf("%s %d", nameOfClass[i], &numOfGrades[i]);`

Comment: scanf("%s %d", nameOfClass[i], &numOfGrades[i]); remove the & sign from nameOfClass[i]

Comment: 1) `scanf("%s %d",...` should employ a width limit like `scanf("%29s %d",...`  2) Using a non-square 2D array like `nameOfClass[30][40];` is more illustrative.  Perhaps something like `char nameOfClass[numOfClasses][100]; int numOfGrades[numOfClasses];  ... scanf("%99s %d",...`